# angular-seed POST acts differently for each browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, browser, cross-browser

I'm not sure what is going on with my http post method.  From what I was reading, there might be something wrong with my security, but I am not really sure that is the case or how to fix it.  Any insight in the right direction would be nice.

I am trying to post to an API and retrieve a response back and return the data.  When I run the POST in IE, I get the proper response.

However when I try this in Chrome I get weird results.  My POST turns into an OPTIONS method.  With a Status Code of 200 OK, but my Response is blank.  And when I try to go to the url directly without the POST I get this displayed in the browser:

> {"result":false,"error":"Authentication failed: Session authentication failed: No Host Name specified Authentication State: Invalid Login"}

Here is the test.js (controller)

```
var host = '255.255.255.255';
var creds = {'logintype':'1','host':host,'user':'Administrator','password':'1234','controlid':'ABC999'};
//var obj = JSON.stringify(creds);


angular.module('myApp.test', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/test', {
      templateUrl: 'test/test.html',
      controller: 'TestCtrl',
      resolve: {
          friends: ['$http', function($http) {
          return $http({url: 'http://192.168.2.164/ISAPI/rip.dll/REST/SESSIONS/',method: 'POST', data: creds })
              .success(function (data) {
                  return data;
              })
              .error(function () {
                  return 'Error';
              });
      }]
  }
});
}])
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'friends',function($scope,response) {
    $scope.response = response;
}]);
```

Comment: The OPTIONS call is happening because Chrome does something called a "preflight" for cross-domain requests. You shouldn't need to stringify the creds object. Just pass it directly to $http's data option. That could be part of the issue, so I recommend trying that first and updating the question.

Comment: I have removed the STRINGIFY and I still receive the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to itsananderson, I was able to resolve my issue.  I was happening because Chrome does something called a "preflight" for cross-domain requests.  I needed to move the API to be on the same server as the site was being run to avoid cross site scripting.